# C++: Vector of pointers does not react to changes

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to C++, right now am working with some pointers. Let's say that I have a vector of pointers,  I push_back one element, call it k2 and then make pointer k2 point to k3. This change affects k2 but doesn't affect vector. What should I have done to make this change affect also the vector?

```cpp
struct Node
{
    Node()
    {
        visited_print = false;
        visited_find = false;
    }
    bool visited_print;
    bool visited_find;
    int value;
    std::vector<Node*> children;
    Node *parent;
};

int main(){
    Node *k1 = new Node();
    Node *k2 = new Node();
    k2->value = 10;
    Node *k3 = new Node();
    k3->value = 100;
    k1->children.push_back(k2);
    k2 = k3;

}
```

In the example above `k1->children[0]->value` equals to `k2->value` (10).

What I want is the value of `k1->children[0]->value` to be `k3->value` (100).

Comment: You mean like `k2->value = k3->value;`

Comment: Or you could change the whole object: `(*k2) = (*k3);` Here you assign the content of the object pointed at by `k3` to the content of the object pointed at by `k2`.

Comment: Yes, I meant changing the whole object. Your second comment actually did what I asked for. Vector was affected but @Celal Ergün said it's not possible, what he meant by that?

Comment: I didn't say it's not possible. I said it does not work that way. You would have changed the value of the memory k2 points to using "k2->value = 555". You cannot change a pointer with another to change the value. Just change the value. All you do by "k2 = k3" is changing a local pointer variable. Not the memory it points to.

Comment: @Celal Ergün  Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. Once you have pushed back your k2, which points to some memory you have allocated, you have saved it into the vector. So you have a pointer pointing to a memory location that has 10 in it. After assigning k3 to k2, you have only changed a pointer variable to point to another memory location which has 100 in it. You wouldn't even delete k2 after this point, you have lost the pointer to that memory. This is called a memory leak.

You can change the pointer you have saved in your vector instead. This way you still have access to your old data. I do not recommend overwriting this pointer either. You wouldn't access the memory you have allocated for your data.

```
struct Node
{
    Node()
    {
        visited_print = false;
        visited_find = false;
    }
    bool visited_print;
    bool visited_find;
    int value;
    std::vector<Node*> children;
    Node *parent;
};

int main(){
    Node *k1 = new Node();
    Node *k2 = new Node();
    k2->value = 10;
    Node *k3 = new Node();
    k3->value = 100;
    k1->children.push_back(k2);
    //k2 = k3;

    delete k2;
    k1->children[0] = k3;
}
```